# Spring streamBridge create rabbitmq queue on startup

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

Since spring deprecated `org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Output` annotation.
I'm using streamBridge new api.

And I wonder what is the best way to auto create the queue automatically on startup like the behaviour of the annotation.

I found a workaround using `spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=myChannel` just to create the queue

As in this sample

```
    @Bean
    fun myChannel(): Supplier<Flux<Message<String>>> = Supplier {
        Flux.empty()
    }
```

and application.properties:

```
bindings:
    myChannel-out-0:
    destination: Mystuff
    producer:
       required-groups: mychannel
```

When I was using `@Output` annotation the queue was created automatically.

Is there another more elegant solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still don't need to do that (pre-create the queue), since once you execute the first `streamBridge.send` the destination will be resolved (queue will be created) and your properties applied.
That said, if you still want to do it you can use `spring.cloud.stream.source` property and point to the name of the destination that you would identify with @Output in the older versions. For example `spring.cloud.stream.source=foo`.